# Find and count common 1(TRUE) and 0(FALSE) between two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array, `a`, that needs to be compared to its respective ground truth, `gt`. For example, say these two arrays are:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]])

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])

gt = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]])

array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

I want to count how 1's were correctly predicted by this and how many 0's.

I can determine the common elements by `common_ = a == gt` :

```
array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True]])
```

which is not what I am after, it just gives all the common elements, and a count of this is not what I want. How will I determine the common highs and common lows separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((1-a)*(1-gt)).sum()` gives you the common 0's and `(a*gt).sum()` gives you the common 1's.

Answer (score 1):

You need two masks, one to check which values in `a` (or `b`) have a certain value, and another to check which values match on both arrays:

```
m1=a==1
m2=a==gt
ones=(m1&m2).sum()
#2
zeros=(m2&~m1).sum()
#1
```